# Auto Generated filter row not auto sizing to column size

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, devexpress

So I am using a third party grid and the issue I have at present is when i adjust the width of the columns cause the filter row is auto generated by the control it shows off in the gui.

https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/400543/xamarin-forms/data-grid/index

Here you will see situation in pic. You will see at the arrows that their lines are no longer lining up on the filter row and was wondering how would over come this their is a filtertemplate data template but no docs on how to use it.

[image]

```
<dxg:DataGridView x:Name="dgWeightLifting"  
 ShowAutoFilterRow="True" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
 PullToRefresh="dgWeightLifting_PullToRefresh"  
 DoubleTap="dgWeightLifting_DoubleTap" 
 HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  HeightRequest="1000" >
 
  <dxg:DataGridView.CellStyle>
   <dxg:CellStyle  BackgroundColor="#333333" BorderColor="#515151"
    FontSize="14" FontColor="White" 
    SelectionColor="#f78a09" SelectionFontColor="Black"/>
  </dxg:DataGridView.CellStyle>

  <dxg:DataGridView.ColumnHeaderStyle >
    <dxg:ColumnHeaderStyle BackgroundColor="#333333" 
     BorderColor="#515151" FontSize="16" FontColor="#929292" 
     Padding="10,10,10,10" FontAttributes="Bold" 
     HorizontalLineThickness="2"  />
  </dxg:DataGridView.ColumnHeaderStyle>

  <dxg:DataGridView.Columns >
      <dxg:TextColumn  FieldName="PlayersId" AllowSort="True" 
       FixedStyle="Start" Caption="PlayersId" Width="2*"  />
       <dxg:TextColumn  FieldName="Players.FullName" 
       FixedStyle="Start" AllowSort="True"  Caption="FullName" 
       Width="2*"  />
       <dxg:TemplateColumn FieldName="BikeCalories" Caption="Bike" 
       IsReadOnly="true" AllowSort="False"  MinWidth="150">
       <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="15, 0, 0, 0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding 
            Item.BikeCalories, StringFormat ='Calories: {0}'}" 
            Grid.Row="0"></Label>
            <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding 
            Item.BikeSeconds, StringFormat = 'Seconds: {0}'}" 
            Grid.Row="2"></Label>
           </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
         </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
        </dxg:TemplateColumn>

       <dxg:TemplateColumn FieldName="TB" Caption="TB" 
        IsReadOnly="true" AllowSort="False" MinWidth="100" 
        Width="100" >
        <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="15, 0, 0, 0">
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Item.TB, 
             StringFormat ='Weight: {0}'}" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
             <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Item.TBReps, 
              StringFormat = 'Reps: {0}'}" Grid.Row="2"></Label>
              </Grid> 
             </DataTemplate>
            </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
           </dxg:TemplateColumn>

            <dxg:TemplateColumn FieldName="OP" Caption="OverHead Press"      IsReadOnly="true" AllowSort="False" MinWidth="100">

                <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="15, 0, 0, 0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label TextColor="White"  Text="{Binding Item.OP, StringFormat ='Weight: {0}'}" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
                            <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Item.OPReps, StringFormat = 'Reps: {0}'}" Grid.Row="1"></Label>


                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
            </dxg:TemplateColumn>

            <dxg:TemplateColumn FieldName="BP" Caption="Bench Press"      IsReadOnly="true" AllowSort="False" MinWidth="100">

                <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="15, 0, 0, 0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Item.BP, StringFormat ='Weight: {0}'}" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
                            <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Item.BPReps, StringFormat = 'Reps: {0}'}" Grid.Row="1"></Label>


                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
            </dxg:TemplateColumn>


            <dxg:TemplateColumn FieldName="PU" Caption="Pull Up"  FixedStyle="End"     IsReadOnly="true" AllowSort="False" MinWidth="100">

                <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="15, 0, 0, 0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label TextColor="White" IsVisible="{Binding Item.Seconds}" Text="{Binding Item.Seconds, StringFormat = 'Seconds: {0}'}" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
                            <Label TextColor="White" IsVisible="{Binding Item.APullUpIsVisible}" Text="{Binding Item.PullUpHolds , StringFormat = 'Pull Up Hold Reps: {0}'}" Grid.Row="2"></Label>
                            <Label TextColor="White" IsVisible="{Binding Item.APullUpIsVisible}" Text="{Binding Item.PullUpHoldSeconds, StringFormat = 'Pull Up Hold Seconds: {0}'}" Grid.Row="3"></Label>

                            <Label TextColor="White"  IsVisible="{Binding Item.PullUpIsVisible}"  x:Name="pullUpRep" Text="{Binding Item.PUReps, StringFormat = 'PUReps: {0}'}" Grid.Row="4"></Label>
                            <Label TextColor="White"  Text="{Binding Item.PullUpType,  StringFormat = 'Type: {0}',Converter={StaticResource PullUpTypeConvertor}}"  Grid.Row="5"></Label>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
            </dxg:TemplateColumn>


        </dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
    </dxg:DataGridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was rather more simple than that I remember in the old days you had to refresh the grid after populating and thus the lines are now aligning up again.

[image]

I simply had to call

```
dgWeightLifting.RefreshData();
```

Where I was loading my items and the control repainted itself correctly.